# Copying atribute table for new shp file

Tags: qgis

i already copied the selected layer from layer 1 to layer 2.But the atribute in layer 2 only contain id.How can i get the field just like the second images for my selected feature in layer 2 ??

[image]
[image]

Comment: Need a lot more information on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: i've edited my question.hopefully it make my question clearer than before @Matthew

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Thank you for taking the new user [tour].  Your question needs more info - please [edit] to explain the process you followed to create Layer 1 and copy the features.

Comment: @Matthew i've edited my question

Comment: @Yogi2296 You have edited but not provided any extra information.  How did you create Layer 1 and how did you copy the features?

Comment: i used add vector layer to open my layer 1.the way i copied it,i select a certain feature>>edit toogle>ctrlc (in layer 1)>>create new shape file (layer 2)>>paste it. @Midavalo

Comment: @Yogi2296 Please **[Edit]** your question to include *ALL* information.  Potential answerers should not need to read all comments to get the full picture of your scenario and question.  Comments are for users to request additional info or clarification from you, your response should be as an [edit] to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shapefile into which you are pasting the features must have the same attribute schema.  Then, they should automatically fill in the right fields when pasting.

If you are just trying to make a new shapefile that is just a subset of an existing shapefile, it would probably be easier to select the desired features, then right click on the layer in the table of contents and save the layer as a new shapefile.  Make sure to check the "Save only selected features" checkbox.

Comment: it said " Export to vector file failed.
Error: creation of layer failed (OGR error:Failed to create file 11.shp: Permission denied) " for the 2nd solution.i've done just like what you said @1saac

Comment: Most probably you did not specify a **new** filename and a folder where you have write access. By default, saving goes to qgis/bin which is wrong in most cases.

Comment: @Yogi2966 That sounds like you do not have permission to write to the folder.  Do you have write access in this directory?

Comment: i've edited my question @1saac

Comment: @Yogi2296 You have not indicated there was any error in your question.  Please **[edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/244324/edit)** your question to include **all** relevant information about what you've tried and the result including errors.